# How can I push elements in an array outside of d3.json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, asynchronous, d3.js

I need to load two json files and loop through them to extract the values I need. The first loop loads a file per page (in the code file1_page=${i}.json), which has contains id's that I would use to then load the information of the second file based on id. I then need to take the data I need from the second for loop and push it in to an array outside of the json objects. I understand that javaScript is asynchronous so it doesn't wait until the bit which pushes the array finishes before it outputs the array I want. I have managed to defer the issue using setTimeout although, the time to wait will vary depending on the size of the files so I cannot preset that to be sure that it will always wait for enough.

Therefore what I need is a way for the code to decide on it's own when the for loops are finished.

```
function update_league_picks (selected_league){
    
    var league_picks = []

    for (let i=1; i<=20;i++){
        d3.json(`file1_page=${i}.json`, function(error, league_players) {
            if (error) throw error;

            var players_page = league_players["standings"]["results"]

            var gw = 2

            for (let j=0; j<players_page.length; j++){
                team_id = players_page[j].entry

                d3.json(`file2_id=${j}.json`, function(error, opp_data) {
                    if (error) throw error;

                    league_picks.push({"active_chip":opp_data.active_chip)
                })
            }

        })
    }
    console.log(league_picks)
    
    // setTimeout(function() {
    //  console.log(league_picks)
    // }, 100000)
    
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `d3.json()` for this? Why not a more "generic" `fetch()`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `json` or `d3.js` hence these tags are not relevant for this question.